# Adding User-Agent & IP to a stored Session -RecordNotSaved -Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, save, rollback

I'm currently building an in-house analytics system which tracks where a visitor clicks throughout each session, whether they are logged into a User account or are a visitor without an account.

I am currently saving my sessions to the database thanks to changes made through sessions_store.rb, however in addition to the session_id, I am trying to figure out how to add both UserAgent details and a visitor's IP to the sessions table.

I've tried a couple solutions but all have failed - my current solution appears to be the closest, however I keep encountering an ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved error after updating the Session's attributes.

I am currently using a before filter in application controller:

```
before_filter :set_useragent_and_ip_in_session

  def set_useragent_and_ip_in_session
    if session
      sess = request.session_options[:id]
      @session = Session.where(session_id: sess).first
      @session.update_attributes(:ip=>request.remote_ip, :user_agent=>request.user_agent)
      @session.save!
    else
    end
  end
```

I've inserted a debugging statement in my views and have played around the code in pry - the @session is valid and displays the @session.user_agent properly .... however when saving to the DB it justs rollsback.

When I use save!, I receive a Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in the logs in addition to the following (pasted to gist to conserve space):
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8019c2426334f395a5fd

Thanks! Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend rethinking your schema. A session can last many requests and you want a record per request. Also notice how your moving data off the request object and trying to store them into a session table. Instead make your very own request table and make a before filter that moves all the data you want from the request object to the request table. Now a session will have many requests.

I'm not sure why your record isn't saving however I would wager naming a model Session is conflicting with rails. By that same token when you make your request table you should give it a unique name like maybe SessionMeta and RequestMeta. Then SessionMeta could have many RequestMeta.